# Cannot get results from Wordpress database using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Query is as following

```
SELECT `sID` FROM `subscribers` where `Email` LIKE '%xxx@xxx.com%'
```

and

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
$hostname = "dd";
$username = "cc";
$password = "aa";
$dbName = "bb";


$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$conn -> select_db("$dbName") or die( "Unable to select database");

check_subscriber($email, $first, $last, $company, $tablename);
function check_subscriber($email, $first, $last, $company, $tablename)
{
    global $wpdb; 
    $emailid=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $subscribercheck = "SELECT `sID` FROM `$tablename` where `Email` LIKE '%$emailid%'";
    $subscriber_exists = "";
    $subscriber_exists = $wpdb -> get_results($wpdb->prepare("$subscribercheck",object));
    var_dump($subscriber_exists);

    if(count($subscriber_exists)>0){
        foreach ($subscriber_exists as $subs)
        {
            echo $sid = $subs-> sID;
        }
    }
    else {
        $wpdb -> insert('subscribers', array(
            'First Name' => $first,
            'Last Name' => $last,
            'Company' => $company,
            'Email' => $email,
            'Date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ));
    }
}
```

`var_dump = NULL`

I tried running the query in our database and it worked, but it doesn't seem to be running here. Please help!

Every variables are defined. `var_dump = NULL` so it goes to `"else"` clause where `wpdb -> Insert` happens and works.

```
$subscriber_exists = $wpdb -> get_results($wpdb->prepare("$subscribercheck",object));
```

However, does not give me any value even though I can run it in our database.

Comment: 1st observation:  don't use the mysql functions - they've been deprecated for years and removed from PHP 7.   use PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: [Turn on error reporting](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm), and let us know what errors you are getting.

Comment: _"I tried running the query in our database and it worked, but it doesn't seem to be running here"_ This doesnt really help us as you are not explaining your different environments.

Comment: I believe the problem lies on your db connections. Initially you connect to your database using `mysql_connect`, but then you use the object `$wpdb` to run your queries, which seems to be using PDO. How are you linking the connection you initially made, with that object? you might need to do something like this: `$wpdb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');`

Comment: I don't see `$tablename` defined anywhere...

Comment: Right, so I am creating this php page where it receives info from ajax and inputs them into our database. I also think the problem is connecting to database... I just tried your suggestion but no luck

Comment: Sorry every variables are defined.

Comment: you're using Wordpress right? If so, have you mofified your `wp-config.php` file ?

Comment: Yes I am. I haven't modified wp-config.php for this use. Where am I suppose to look?

Comment: I believe `$wpdb` looks at the connection settings coming from `wp-config.php`. Place your settings there. it is located in the root directory of your wordpress installation.

Comment: I tried and looked, everything looks like what they are supposed to be... thanks a lot for helping though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the problems I found:

- you are attempting a database connection manually while Wordpress already sets this up for you via `wp-config.php`. Remove the piece of code that you use to connect and use the `$wpdb` object to run your queries.
- you are using `$wpdb->prepare()` but you are not setting the necessary parameters correctly. If you want to use prepared statements you need to understand how they work first, [read here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)
- since you are not making use of prepared statements then run your normal query without it.
- Make sure that your table is located in the same database that wordpress is setup for.

This is how I would redo your code:

```
function check_subscriber($email, $first, $last, $company, $tablename) {
    global $wpdb;

    $email = $wpdb->esc_like($email);

    $query = "SELECT `sID` FROM `$tablename` where `Email` LIKE '%$email%'";

    $subscribers = $wpdb->get_results($query, object);

    if (count($subscribers) > 0) {
        foreach ($subscribers as $subs) {
            echo $sid = $subs->sID;
        }
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert('subscribers', array(
            'First Name' => $first,
            'Last Name' => $last,
            'Company' => $company,
            'Email' => $email,
            'Date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ));
    }
}
```

However, if you really want to use prepared statements, use this:

```
function check_subscriber($email, $first, $last, $company, $tablename) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT `sID` FROM `$tablename` where `Email` LIKE %s";

    $like_email = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($email) . '%';

    $subscribers = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare($query, $like_email),
        object
    );

    if (count($subscribers) > 0) {
        foreach ($subscribers as $subs) {
            echo $sid = $subs->sID;
        }
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert('subscribers', array(
            'First Name' => $first,
            'Last Name' => $last,
            'Company' => $company,
            'Email' => $email,
            'Date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ));
    }
}
```